# Contact avatar colors

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-5

What do the different color contact avatars mean? My Samsung automatically generates avatars for new contacts. I'm wondering what the different colors mean. I can't figure out the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Different colors on contact avatars are randomly generated from an array of colors. If you look at the [Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master/res/values/colors.xml) of Contacts app, you will find something like this in a `xml` file.

```
<array name="letter_tile_colors">
    <item>#DB4437</item>
    <item>#E91E63</item>
    <item>#9C27B0</item>
    <item>#673AB7</item>
    <item>#3F51B5</item>
    <item>#4285F4</item>
    <item>#039BE5</item>
    <item>#0097A7</item>
    <item>#009688</item>
    <item>#0F9D58</item>
    <item>#689F38</item>
    <item>#EF6C00</item>
    <item>#FF5722</item>
    <item>#757575</item>
</array>
```

This array consists of HEX color codes for different colors.
So when you create new contact, a `function` will pick any color at random from that array and it will be assigned to the avatar.
Since, the color is assigned at random, you won't find any particular pattern.