# Google contacts background color change

Tags: google-contacts, 8.0-oreo, moto-x4

From Dec 2017, I am using my new Android device attached with my old Google id. The contacts got automatically synced. And, works without any issues. But, today I have noticed that, one of the contact's background(default color added automatically) color got changed automatically. I haven't edited contact.(Sometimes editing contact changes color).

For Example: Contact A: contact's background is black previously, now changed to Pink. Contact B: contact's background is green previously, now changed to Dark red.(N.B: Contact A and B have the most number of call logs in my phone)

Why's this happening like this? What's the logic behind it? If it is regular/normal, does this happen in any interval? I haven't noticed this on previous device.

Comment: Related question https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190597/131553

Comment: @beeshyams there's a difference. I have mentioned that color got automatically changed without any change.

Comment: That's why said it is related , didn't flag as duplicate