# What what do the colors represent an Android 11

Tags: contacts

Hi I have an Android 11 Motorola phone and I was wondering what the colors represent next to the contacts and also the colors that are different using during the text

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Contact avatar colors](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/190597/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contact avatar colors](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190597/contact-avatar-colors)